# Count all cells in a Google Sheet with multiple tabs

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet with multiple tabs which is being filled in via API.
I'm aware of the Google Spreadsheet limitation of 5 million cells. What is the best way to determine how close I am to this limit?

My thinking was to use a custom query to loop through the tabs and count all cells. Is this the best way?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. For future reference:

```js
function getTotalCells() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    var lastRow = sheet.getMaxRows();
    var lastColumn = sheet.getMaxColumns();
    var sheetTotal = lastRow * lastColumn;
    sum += sheetTotal;
  }

  return sum;
}
```